# Hibernate JoinTable multiple types

Tags: java, hibernate, join

I'm trying to set up a many to many relationship between two entities, where there are multiple relationship types.

For example, lets say we have a table "course", a table "person", and a mapping table "course_person". Any given course can have instructors, graders, and students, each of which are collections from the person table. Each person can be affiliated with multiple courses in different roles.

The table "course_person" has columns "course_id", "person_id", and "type", where type is "INSTRUCTOR", "GRADER", or "STUDENT".

The Course class would have three different Set members, each one listing the people in the given role. It would look something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "course")
public class Course{
    private Set<Person> instructors;
    private Set<Person> graders;
    private Set<Person> students;

    @ManyToMany(
        targetEntity=Person.class,
        cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}
    )
    @JoinTable(
        name="course_person",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="course_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="person_id")
    )
    @WhereJoinTable(clause="type='INSTRUCTORS'")
    public Set<Person> getInstructors() {
        return this.instructors;
    }

    @ManyToMany(
        targetEntity=Person.class,
        cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}
    )
    @JoinTable(
        name="course_person",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="course_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="person_id")
    )
    @WhereJoinTable(clause="type='GRADER'")
    public Set<Person> getGraders() {
        return this.graders;
    }

    @ManyToMany(
        targetEntity=Person.class,
        cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE}
    )
    @JoinTable(
        name="course_person",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="course_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="person_id")
    )
    @WhereJoinTable(clause="type='STUDENT'")
    public Set<Person> getStudents() {
        return this.students;
    }
}
```

This works fine for reading the data from the database. However, it doesn't work for creating new entries in the map table, because hibernate doesn't know what to set "type" to. I need to find a way to have any Person objects added to "instructors" set type to "INSTRUCTOR", etc, for each relationship type. Is this doable?

Comment: just as a comment using jpa to abstract the persistence provider is a great idea.

Comment: is there a JPA equivalent of WhereJoinTable? or another JPA-compliant way of accomplishing what I want?